# How to turn off the Acer Aspire 7738 Power Button LED light?

Tags: acer-aspire, backlight, led

The Acer Aspire 7738 has a large blue light emitting power button, top left on the keyboard. Its light is rather distracting and I want to turn it off.

How can I disable this light?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

two options:

cut the wire of the LED (will void the warranty!) or use some masking tape on the LED.

Comment: I agree with the tape suggestion. Easy, doesn't mess with warranty, and reversible.